# C# Unity/Mono DLL - Variable suddenly null when passed into function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, mono, nullreferenceexception

Got a very weird problem which doesn't make much sense.

We've got a C# dll being compiled with Unity 3.5 and we're getting a null reference exception due to a variable being null on Android.

We're passing a class into a function and then doing some work on that class in the function. Before passing the object into the function it's normal. Once inside the function, it's null...

This bug only happens when building our Unity project in non-development mode.

Sometimes the null-check we've added in the function actually yields a null reference exception. It's absolutely bizarre. The null check just prints to the output log if there is an error. If we put this null-check in a try catch block then no exceptions are generated and it works as expected. So it can work just by adding some debug code at the top to print if it's null in a try catch block.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have no idea how many others places in the code things like this could be happening. The 'fix' I've got to get it working really isn't a fix, there is some other underlying problem it seems.

(The class we're passing doesn't have any special overload operators etc that would cause a null check on it to cause an exception or anything like that)

A pseudo example of the code:

```
    void FunctionOne(InputClass myVar)
{

    while (memberStack.Empty() == false)
    {
        var stackPop = memberStack.pop();

        if (myVar == null)
        {
            //At this point the myVar will always be non-null
        }

        FunctionTwo(stackPop, myVar);

    }

}

void FunctionTwo(StackVar stckvar, InputClass myVar)
{

    if (myVar == null)
    {
        //Sometimes though at this point, the myVar will suddenly be null
        //myVar IS NULL
    }

    //DO OTHER WORK

}
```

Class Definition of InputClass:

```
    protected class InputClass
    {
        public bool backup;
        public Stack<STRUCT1> plan;
        public Stack<int> locked;
        public int length;
        public Terminate terminate; //ENUM TYPE
        public HashSet<int> unlocked;
        public List<OBJTYPE1> unassigned;
        public List<OBJTYPE1> damaged;
        public List<OBJTYPE1> replacedObjs;

        public bool IsLocked(OBJTYPE1 subOBJ)
        {
            int compressed = subOBJ.compressed;
            return !unlocked.Contains(compressed) || depLocked.Contains(compressed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried passing it as a reference using the *ref* modifier? Like "FuntionTwo(stackpop, ref myVar);" ?

Comment: Yes have tried that. Didn't make any difference though.

Comment: @Comeradealexi - did you ever get this issue resolved?
and has anyone else experienced something similar? (I am experiencing objects which shouldn't be null causing null reference exceptions when running my C# app with Mono on a Unix system)

Comment: @giladrv I think we ended up keeping the 'fix' and upgrading to newer versions of Unity. See if you can re-jiggle the code to get it to magically work is all I can suggest!

Answer (score 0):

Asumed you pass someClassInstance into anotherClass.SomeMethod please try this

```
var localReference = someClassInstance;
if (localReference == null){
  // log it is null before the call
}
anotherClass.SomeMethod(localReference);
```

if you happen to log the null reference, then you did probably forget to set some closure for the instance before.. you would need to track that call then.

Comment: my two cent yout the added Code..
i guess that if void FunctionOne(InputClass myVar) always get a non null object and in FunctionTwo it sometimes is..

Can you create a clone of the Object in FunctionOne?

Do you know more about the Class definition of InputClass ?
Is it e.g. IDisposable and do you call method one in a using{} context?

Comment: Have added an example of the class definition. Haven't posted it exactly as is since I don't think we're allowed to but given an idea of what it contains. It's loads of lists basically. I could try making a copy see if that does anything.